# JPA/Hibernate 50% slower than using simple JDBC

Tags: spring, performance, jpa, slowdown

First I would like to say that I'm far of being an expert with JPA and Hibernate. But I came across something that I'm completely stuck as I don't understand how things are working underneath and don't know how to debug it.

I have a webapp (Spring + JPA2.0). I have an algorithm that calculate a score for a user with data coming from the PostrgeSQL database. To benchmark the speed of the algorithm I have ran the calculation on 1 user.

It took 72 seconds. (i found this time a bit strange because i know it shouldn't take THAT long)

So what I did is replaced the database call (entityManger.createQuery(...)) by a Simple JDBC connection (`conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);)` and I pull the data from the DB without using JPA.

it took 35 seconds to calculate the score for the same user...

Is it normal that using JPA makes the calculation **50%** slower?? I mean I would have think that yes the time would have been "a bit" more than simply using jdbc but **50%** ??

Is there any configuration that i don't know about that would explain this difference?

Here is the pseudo code of the algo. calculateScore is call within a loop 2000 times:

```
public double calculateScore(userId, placeId) {

//This returns in average 5 columns
List<Object[]> datas = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT info1, info2, info3 WHERE user_id=.. and place_id=...").getResultList();
..
..
for (Object[] result : datas) {
 info1 = result[0] // Integer
 info2 = result[1] // Integer
 info3 = result[2] // Double

 if (info3 == null) {
     info3 = calculateMissing(..)
 }

 .. calculation ..

 return result
}

private double calculateMissing(..) {

    //this query returns maximum 20 rows 
    List<Double> data =  entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT info FROM..."). getResultList;


    //So here we could have UP TO 20 call to the db
    while(some cond) {
       data2 =  entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM...).getOne()
       if (data2 ..)
         cond = false
      ..
      }

    ... calculation ..

   return result;
}
```

So here are my "three" little select to the DB.

**EDIT 1**

I have tried narrowing where "exactly" the problem was. I have replaced one by one the call from jdbc to JPA. and it appears that the while loop was the one making the 50% (well almost) time loss. Doing dis was a really bad idea from the start, but I didn't know that JPA was not gonna like this AT ALL.

I have replaced the while loop with a smarter SQL query. And now the algorithm runs in **15 seconds instead of 70 seconds!**

**And in 12 seconds instead of 35 for the JDB version.**

Comment: JPA certainly introduces overhead, particularly relating to reflection, but those kinds of times suggest that there's something else fundamentally very wrong with your approach.

Comment: I will edit my question to include more detail on the type of selects, data size etc..

Comment: My guess, the data retrieved by your query is far less then the data retrieved when using JPA (maybe due to some collections eagerly fetched etc.).

Comment: All the collection in my entities are using FETCH.LAZY. But to make things more or less even i have used createNativQuery

Comment: Code smell : You are performing some extreme operations on the result list after getting it from the database without filtering (if any) which are supposed to be performed on the database side (through JPA). Executing an SQL statement inside a loop to get a generalized list first and then performing operations on the list on the front-end does not appear to be a good practice. Those test cases in essence, do not appear to be sane test-cases (though ORMs basically tend to be somewhat slow but that should not be too much, if optimization techniques are used precisely).

Comment: At least part of the problem is that you keep recreating instead of reusing queries, but this looks like the sort of aggregate operation you should be performing in SQL and just returning the result.

Comment: Spot on @Tiny. I have updated the Question with more details. But indeed that while loop is the culprit... and chrylis thanks for this also, by creating the query only once it also made a quite noticeable improvement

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced very large differences between JPA/Hibernate and JDBC when retrieving records by their primary key.

The differences can be particularly large if it's a flat object model. As the model complexity increases, the performance becomes more even.

Also, consider that using JPA implies the creation of a connection pool when the app starts (which is not necessary the case with JDBC), so the first transaction in special could take considerably longer with JPA than with JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it seems that speed difference between hibernate/jdbc is significant for small queries. On the other hand when you try it with big list of results the preformance is quite similar.

It is really not bad in practical usage. Small queries still run *fast enough*. Long running queries (which should be your main concern) have similar performance.